# Is every complex linear algebraic group a differential Galois group?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, galois-theory, lie-groups

Let $ G $ be a complex linear algebraic group. In other words, $ G $ is a subvariety of the space of $ n \times n $ complex matrices and $ G $ is a group under matrix multiplication.

Does there exist a differential equation for which $ G $ is the differential Galois group?

(If so could someone give an example of a differential equation with differential Galois group $ SL_2(\mathbb{C}) $? Any other simple example would also be appreciated. Thanks!)

Comment: The title question is still open! But I think I found the example: $ SL_2(\mathbb{C})=DifGal(E/K) $ where $ K=\mathbb{C}(t) $ is the field of rational functions and $ E $ is the splitting field of the Airy differential operator $ u''(t)-tu(t) $. Source is theorem 4 of http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hubbard/diffalg1.pdf

Comment: A linear differential equation (otherwise the differential field doesn't have to be finitely generated and an automorphism is probably not represented by a matrix)